# UINavigationController barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer always nil

Tags: ios, uinavigationcontroller, swift, ios8

I want to animate the status bar (show/hide) alongside my navigation bar (show/hide) animations. I'm trying to add my view controller as a target to the bar hide on tap gesture recognizer of the containing navigation controller. Unfortunately the gesture recognizer reference is always nil. I have set the hide bars on tap toggle to true in my storyboard file.

```
override func viewDidAppear(animated: Bool)  {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)

    if navigationController {
        if navigationController.barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer {
            navigationController.barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer.addTarget(self, action: Selector("barHideTappedWithRecognizer:"))
        } else {
            println("Bar hide on tap gesture recognizer is nil!")
        }
    }
 }
```

This code always prints: Bar hide on tap gesture recognizer is nil!

I'm running iOS 8 beta 4.

Comment: Wheredo you add the barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer?

Comment: I believe the barHideOnTapGestureRecognizer is supposed to be created automatically by the framework whenever a UINavigationController is created.